# How do I view messages in a discussion group on a per-message basis (Facebook)?

Tags: facebook

One of the incredibly annoying features of infinite scrolling (such as on your own timeline or in a discussion group) is that it will make the page slower and slower, and clog the memory of the page. At some point, the browser will be out of memory. It would be much nicer if, instead of infinite scrolling, I can see the messages on my timeline / discussion group on a per-message basis: this frees the memory associated with the last post, and therefore I can actually "scroll" infinitely.

However, I cannot seem to find this feature. From a User Experience point of view, I would expect this feature to be there.

How can I view a single message on my timeline / in a discussion group, and then use the arrow keys to go to the next question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible at the current time.